# issues in dragging item in list view

Tags: android

I have created a ListView which contains a list of items. Each item in a list view had a different image. What I want is to drag and drop each of the images in the list view means I can move the position of items in the list view.

The thing I want to do is:

1. I can drag and drop each of the images in the list from one position to another.
2. on click of each image on the list view I want to open a dialog.

So how that can be done? Please help me with suitable example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the code below in **DragNDropListView**.

```
@Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        final int action = ev.getAction();
        final int x = (int) ev.getX();
        final int y = (int) ev.getY();  

        if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN && x < this.getWidth()/4) { 
            mDragMode = true;
        }
```

...

Instead of above code use this for enabling drag-n-drop only in middle of the list view.

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    final int action = ev.getAction();
    final int x = (int) ev.getX();
    final int y = (int) ev.getY();

    int mWidth = this.getWidth() / 4;  //calculating the quarter part
    if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN && x >= (mWidth * 2) && x < (mWidth * 3) ) {
        mDragMode = true;
    }
```

...

1) Whatever the **x** value is coming you need to check it like where you want to make drag-n-drop enable.

2) To give a full privileged to user so that they can drag from any point of the lsit item 
 use this

```
if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN ) //don't check for x-position.
{
..
}
```

Please look the above codes,

Hope this will help you.

@Anshuman nice question by the way.

Comment: is it possible to do it onLongPress of an image view that i have used in listItem...if so how that can be done...

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=drag%20and%20drop%20example%20in%20android%20%20listview%20ericharlow&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CFkQFjAC&url=http://ericharlow.blogspot.com/2010/10/experience-android-drag-and-drop-list.html&ei=jsK8T5D3EcLSrQftorC1Dw&usg=AFQjCNEqVMKCVxxrP0TSWxnd3iaidbxUuQ&cad=rja) very simple example given by Eric Harlow.

He used

```
private ArrayList<String> mContent; //in DragNDropAdapter class
```

As you requirement to use **Images**, customize it in **whole package** with

```
private ArrayList<Image> mContent; //in DragNDropAdapter class
```

Comment: Yep i go through the app and it works great. But I lost the ability to click and scroll. How to I retain those two?I was thinkng the drag and drop should happen on long press of the item instead of a normal press.

Comment: when you click on icmpmove.png (area) than only it starts drag-N-drop.

Comment: Yep i know but what if i user want to drag it from the middle position of an ListItem...so we have to give a full privileged to user so that they can drag from any point of the lsit item